# Translation of マネージャー

Tags: translation

> じゃあ, 一緒にこれ飲もうよ。さっきマネージャーに差し入れでもらってさ。

Well, マネージャー is manager. If here was "dispenser" instead "manager" it would be understandable. So what "manager" doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of `差し入れ` is "food/provisions provided for someone (who is busy with some task)". So, the sentence could be translated as:

> Well, let's drink this together. The manager brought it earlier for us [while we were working].

Another sign that `マネージャー` is a person here is the verb `もらう`, which can be applied only to people (though I guess personification is possible).

If you're not familiar with usage of `もらう`, here's a pretty detailed post on the four verbs to express giving and receiving:

http://lang-8.com/90163/journals/417636

In your sentence, the speaker received something from the manager and is expressing gratitude for it.

Comment: Nowhere in the original is gratitude expressed or "while we were working" said.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put it in [], to show that it's implied.